# 2011 13inch MBP - Can I use 2 external displays - one with MINI DVI and one with Thunderbolt?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have 2011 13 inch MBP running OSX Mavericks (10.9.4). 2.3 GHz i5 processor, 8GB DDR3 Memory and Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB (VRAM) Graphics.

I want to know if I can run 2 external monitors **alongside** my MBP display. That would make a total of 3 Monitors - 2 external and the MBP monitor.

I have read about solutions like Matrox DualHead2Go but I would like to know if there is anyway I can use one display on the Mini DVI port and the other on the Thunderbolt port?

I would prefer a solution which didn't require me to combine 2 monitors into 1 screen like the Matrox does. The reason for this is: I would like to use fullscreen apps on all 3 monitories.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question, see: [Can I have multiple monitors on my MacBook Pro (Early 2011)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62537/can-i-have-multiple-monitors-on-my-macbook-pro-early-2011)

> Any 2011 MacBook Pro model will support Thunderbolt. You can daisy-chain 2 Thunderbolt displays. You can also connect one mini DisplayPort monitor to the end of a Thunderbolt chain and connect your Mac to your Thunderbolt Display.
>
> A non-Thunderbolt solution if you don't have a Thunderbolt Mac: a DisplayLink-style USB to DVI display adapter.